# What is the most efficient way to align these posts with Bootstrap4 and Flask?

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I'm building a web application with Python 3.6, Flask, Bootstrap4, and Postgresql on a Windows 10 OS.
Right now, I'm just using dummy data to test the application and I'm running it on my local machine.

The application is supposed to take the first four posts in a dataset (posts) and display the first post in a row of its own with a width of 12 columns.
Then it's supposed to display the next three posts side-by-side each with a width of 3 columns.
I can get the application to produce the right widths and to display the first post correctly. However, instead of putting the second, third, and fourth posts side-by-side, it is putting them all underneath each other.

In other words, It should look like this...

```
--------1--------
--2-- --3-- --4--
```

But it's coming out like this...

```
--------1--------
--2--
--3--
--4--
```

I tried stripping it of all styling and removing a lot of the class identifies except for "row" and the "col-md-12" and "col-md-4" classes. I thought maybe something with the specific styling was messing it up, but I got essentially the same result.

Here's a snippet of my code.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
    'author': 'JOHN DOE',
    'title': 'Blog Post 1',
    'content': 'Most recent content.',
    'date_posted': '01/01/2019'
    },
    {
    'author': 'JOHN DOE',
    'title': 'Blog Post 2',
    'content': 'Secondary content.',
    'date_posted': '01/01/2019'
    },
    {
    'author': 'JOHN DOE',
    'title': 'Blog Post 3',
    'content': 'Secondary content.',
    'date_posted': '01/01/2019'
    },
    {
    'author': 'JOHN DOE',
    'title': 'Blog Post 4',
    'content': 'Secondary content.',
    'date_posted': '01/01/2019'
    }
]

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", landing=True, posts=posts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block landing %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
            <div class="row">
                <article class="media content-section col-md-12">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>

                    <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        {% elif loop.index <= 4 %}
            <div class="row">
                <article class="media content-section col-md-4">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>

                    <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock landing %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your home.html using the below code

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block landing %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                <article class="media content-section col-md-12">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>

                    <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </article>
        {% elif loop.index <= 4 %}
                <article class="media content-section col-md-4">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>

                    <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                </article>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock landing %}
```